# symfony hide fields but validate on them

Tags: php, forms, symfony, entity

I have a strange issue with one of my entities.

my Vehicle entity has the following db table fields:

- orders (PK)
- licenseplate (PK)
- make
- model
- variant

On the form the only field visible is the licenseplate.

After the field there is a button where the visitor fetches the make/model/variant data from a ajax call to a AjaxController that adds the data to the db. (there is a $session 'orderId' that sets the 'orders' field).

I need to be absolutely certain that the visitor has fetched the make/model/variant and that the visitor cannot change the make/model/variant data.

How can I check on form submit that the vehicle table is filled out? Can I do a Doctrine check and set the form to 'invalid'?

Thank you for your time.

Regards, Lars Hansen

Comment: Why not fetch the ajax data and populate the form's hidden fields and include that data with your submit? That way you can just make the fields required (but hidden) which makes use of standard validation.

Also why are the fields hidden if the user has to select the make/model/variant? Wouldn't they want to see what they have selected?

Comment: Hi @Richard - the fields are not present in the <form> because the user may not be able to change the values.


My ajax call returns the make/model/variant as a string so the user can see that it is the right car. 


But I want to make sure that the user doesn't change the make/model/variant values so I save them in the ajax call.


But at the same time I want to make sure in the form submit that the user has fetched the car data.


Does it make sense?

Comment: That makes sense, there's a lot of ways to do this, I've added one as an answer off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be:

1. Remove make, model and variant from your form. If you don't want the user potentially changing them and you're saving them elsewhere, there's no point having them.
2. Add a hidden, non-mapped field, something like 'dataFetched' to the form.
3. When successfully fetching/saving the car data via ajax, set this field checked/true
4. Via javascript, don't allow form submission until the dataFetched field is checked.
5. In a PRE_SUBMIT listener, check that dataFetched is true and if not, invalidate the form (because a JS check is not sufficient on its own). See CsrfValidationListener in the symfony standard package for a listener example. (I'm using 2.3 but I assume it's still there in newer versions).
6. **Optionally** If you wanted to keep make/model/variant in the form. In the listener you could also check that make/model/variant
   corresponds to what you would expect it to (in case the user changes
   it) & invalidate the form at that point.

Comment: how can I check the make/model/variant in the Listener? 

As far as I know the Doctrine isn't available in the "EntityType"? Can it be injected?

Comment: Yes, you can inject doctrine / entitymanager into a form type (and by extension the listener) no problems. You can do it directly as a constructor argument or define the form type as a service and inject the entitymanager that way. Listeners themselves also have access to the underlying entity objects in the form.

Comment: Hi @Richard - I've accepted your answer - do you have any examples where the injection works? I've searched google all yesterday without any luck. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Hello! Form as a service (allows DI): http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#defining-your-forms-as-services - Entity Listener for forms: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html - should be everything you need there.